# nth-child and before

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm having an CSS problem, i need to achieve this

```
article div#comments-wrapper ul.sub-comment:before {
    width:1px;
    height:67px;
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-595px;
    margin-top:-36px;
    content:'';
}
article div#comments-wrapper ul.sub-comment:nth-child(1):before {
    height:37px;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
```

but i can't put two pseudo elements like that, and i've tested it (doesn't work),
also tried some other ways but didn't manage to figure it out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that works. What problem exactly are you facing?

Comment: This is valid, but the current implementations may have trouble interpreting it properly.

Comment: The following works: http://jsfiddle.net/9KkeK/. So your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9KkeK/1/ i posted my code there, one line should be red and other blue.. :S

Comment: Ah, the classic problem of using `:nth-child()` with classes. Will you have an arbitrary number of `.sub-comment` items (i.e. not just 2)?

Comment: Yes, i'll be having 0-xx number of .sub-comment items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child()` doesn't filter by classes or anything. In your code, your first `ul.sub-comment` isn't the very first child in `#comments-wrapper`, so it doesn't work.

Instead, use [this selector technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/106224) and invert your `height` and `margin-top` styles as follows:

```
article div#comments-wrapper ul.sub-comment:before {
    width:1px;
    height:37px; /* was 67px in your code */
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-595px;
    margin-top:-6px; /* was -36px in your code */
    content:'';
}
article div#comments-wrapper ul.sub-comment ~ ul.sub-comment:before {
    height:67px; /* was 37px in your code */
    margin-top:-36px; /* was -6px in your code */
}
```

Basically, instead of `:nth-child(1)` (or `:first-child` for that matter), use a sibling selector with another `ul.sub-comment` to apply the original styles to all subsequent `ul.sub-comment` elements *after the first one*.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9KkeK/2) (also inverted the `background-color` styles so the first one remains blue)

Answer (score 0):

Use :: for pseudo before and after elements

```
article div#comments-wrapper ul.sub-comment:nth-child(1)::before {
    height:37px;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
```